# How to provide to the user a quicklook experience in a NSTableView in a Cocoa Mac Os X Application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I work with some files in a NSTableView in my Desktop Application, and I would like to react to space bar keyboard shortcuts by providing a quickly experience for various kinds of files. Is there any snippet available anywhere that can point me in the right direction ?

Thanks for any help... !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QLPreviewPanel` for this. It's a subclass of `NSPanel` and `NSWindow`, so you can use `-orderFront:` to show it.

Your controller class should implement the methods of the `QLPreviewPanelController` informal protocol to declare that it can control a Quick Look preview panel and to be notified that it is the controller.

When it is the controller, it can set the panel's delegate and/or data source. It would implement the methods of the respective protocols to provide the items to preview.

Apple provides the [QuickLookDownloader sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/QuickLookDownloader/Introduction/Intro.html) to demonstrate its use.

Comment: You saved our Day Ken ! You are an Angel !! Thank You